# android permission issue : apk not being accepted

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I am submitting a new version of my app. But the developer console doesn't allow me to do so. It says that my app is not compliant with the new policies for the permission (ask for permission at runtime).

But as I can see, I don't use any dangerous permission...

My app is using the following permissions (according to the developer console) : 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="fr.mehfile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" tools:node="remove"/>

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ApplicationMz">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Accueil"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Programs"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Infos"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.NousContacter"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ProgramDetail"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.NewsList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.News"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.TimeTable"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.TimeTableTab"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name="fr.mehfile.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:permission="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the dangerous permission request is coming from a library.

Comment: I found the following list of permissions used by my application (including libraries : 

- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
- com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
- com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

I don't find any dangerous permission on this list...

Comment: My gradle file (dependencies section) : 

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Probably, the problem is in your targetSdk. Also, make release APK, and open this in Android Studio - you will see the **final** AndroidManifest.xml with all the permission dirived from all libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To find where permissions might be originating, you can look at the merged manifest file using Android Studio.   Open your manifest file in Android Studio and the click the "Merged" tab at the bottom of the editor.  Here is a picture for context:

[image]